# missing electron.exe during windows 10 electron-packager

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I've started with a clean VM of windows 10. Installed node.js, npm, upgraded npm and installed electron-packager -g.

I have a simple electron app that I wrote which packages fine on Mac. But when I do this from the app directory:

electron-packager .

It yields:

Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v8.1.0
ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\ROBERT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\myApp-win32-x64\electron.exe' -> 'C:\Users\ROBERT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\myApp-win32-x64\myApp.exe'

However, the electron.exe file doesn't exist in that specified directory.

I'm a noob so I'm probably doing something wrong but I think I followed the correct sequence.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! Judging by your username ROBERT~1 it seems that you have a space in your name. I also had a space. Change your username (a long process) or create a new user (without spaces). That fixed my issue :)
Good luck!

Comment: Perfect! I'm not sure how you figured that one out but getting rid of the spaces did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @BobK I switched laptops and could no longer build an .exe file.. I set DEBUG=electron-packager before building and noticed that half the paths had the ~1 and half had my full name.. My previous laptop had a normal non-spaced name so I figured it had to be the issue :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I started playing with yarn and it seems to play better in the Windows environment, even with spaces in the path. I got a usable setup exe with the following: "yarn add electron-builder --dev" then "yarn electron-builder".